# Configurar porta fixa para projeito Web API Asp.net Core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-web-api

Gostaria de saber como configurar uma porta padrão fixa para minha aplicação Web API no asp.net core.

Comment: Essa questão do SOen pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365277/how-to-specify-the-port-an-asp-net-core-application-is-hosted-on